# Formkit autoanimate doesn't work on my list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, formkit

Formkit autoanimate doesn't work on my list.
I have HospitalList, and there is a div with HospitalItems, i download autoanimate library, applied it, but it doesnt work

My main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import './styles/app.css';
import components from '@/components/UI';
import router from '@/router/index.js';
import store from '@/store';
import { autoAnimatePlugin } from '@formkit/auto-animate/vue'

const app = createApp(App)

components.forEach(component => {
  app.component(component.name, component)
})

app
  .use(autoAnimatePlugin)
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .mount('#app');
```

List:

```html
<div v-auto-animate>
  <HospitalItem
    v-for="hospital in hospitals"
    :key="hospital._id"
    :hospital="hospital"
    @delete-hospital="deleteEmit"
  >
  </HospitalItem>
</div>
```

My HospitalItem:

```
   <div
        class="flex flex-col justify-center xl:w-[1270px] xl:h-[220px] bg-white border-2 px-[20px] py-[20px] mx-2 rounded-[20px] xl:whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-400">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <h1 class="mb-4 font-bold text-[20px] max-w-[1200px] overflow-hidden dark:text-white cursor-pointer"
                @click="() => $router.push({ path: `/hospital/${hospital._id}` })">{{
                    hospital.hospitalName }}</h1>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-trash mr-[10px] dark:text-white text-[20px] cursor-pointer"
                @click="$emit('deleteHospital', hospital._id)"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="flex space-x-2 items-center max-w-1100px overflow-hidden">

            <p class="text-blue-500">{{ hospital.telNum }}</p>
            <span class="dark:text-white">|</span>
            <p class="dark:text-white">{{ hospital.email }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-2 mb-5">
            <p class="dark:text-white">{{ hospital.geoPos }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-2 -[1px] py-2">
            <div>
                <p class="dark:text-white font-bold">{{ hospital.leaderName }}</p>
                <p class="dark:text-white">{{ hospital.leaderJobTitle }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help me fix this

Comment: What is supposed to be the animation trigger?  Are you adding items? Sorting?  Explain the use case.  "doesn't work" doesn't explain much.  How is it not working? Explain actual vs expected result.  Give as much debugging information as you can.  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also, does HospitalItem component have a single root element or multiple?

Comment: There is a delete button on my HospitalItem, and also pagination

Comment: My question (one of them) is concerned with the number of **root** elements, not number of elements in general. Maybe to remove confusion, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78248311/edit) your question and add the component code instead.

Comment: i edited, check please

Comment: nothing I see that would cause a problem.  I run similar code as yours with no issue.  you may need to create a runnable example, providing github repo or maybe [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or other online code sandbox